# express request data is cleaned up if uncaught exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this simple express app:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/foo/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.on('finish', () => console.log("params are:", req.params))
  throw 'big error';
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

`req.params` is `undefined` and I don't understand why. It's `undefined` only if there is an uncaught exception (hence my `throw`), if no exception occurs, `req.params` is still defined.

I printed the complete `req` object and in the case of an exception, a lot a properties changed, like it was cleaned up.